# extract a portion of text from mysql mediumtext field to make turn.js book page with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, joomla

im using  [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/) and custome php code to load joomla articles of a specific category to make a flipbook... its working fine till i have one article for one page. I add/edit article then save it and then view it on book page... this is a tedious task to do... now suppose i have all the content of a book in a joomla article and i want to dynamically load a portion of it as a page to make the book page and so on make pages till end of article... this seems doable if i only have text with fix no of lines. But the problem is the content can have images and headings as well... so how can i dynamically vary the portion of the article to be extracted for a single page based on contents to avoid overflow of book page...

here's the working code of the book where i have one article for one page...

```
<?php  
//get total pages code from uncategorized (default) category. (id=2)
//state 1 means published -2 for trashed         
$qry="SELECT count(*) FROM `sdad_content` WHERE `catid`= '2' and `state` ='1' ";
  $get_db->setQuery($qry);
  $total_pages=$get_db->loadResult();

  if($total_pages){
      $qry="SELECT `id` FROM `sdad_content` WHERE `catid`= '2' AND `state`='1' ORDER BY `id`";
      //echo "<< $qry >>";
      $get_db->setQuery($qry);$get_db->query();
      $total=$get_db->getNumRows();
        if ($total >= 1 ) { //execute this only if we have some results
            $ids = $get_db->loadAssocList();
        }        
  }

//echo $total_pages;          

 for($i=0; $i<$total_pages; $i++){

      $qry="SELECT `introtext` FROM `sdad_content` WHERE `catid`= '2' AND `id`= '".$ids[$i]['id']."'";
      $get_db->setQuery($qry);
      $cover = $get_db->loadResult();
        if($i%2==0){
            $class='even';
            $pnoclass="pnoright";
          }else{
            $class='odd';
            $pnoclass="pnoleft";
          }
          echo '<div class="text '.$class.' "> <div class="page"> '.$cover; 
            echo '<div class="'.$pnoclass.' ">  </div>';
         echo '</div> </div>';

      }


    //code for back cover

     //adjusting the last odd page if ends at odd insert a page to make it even
      if($total_pages%2!=0){
          echo '<div class="text odd "> <div class="page">'; 
            echo '<div class="pnoleft"></div>';
          echo '</div> </div>'; 
      }  

      echo '<div class="text even "> <div class="page"> '.$covers[1]["introtext"]; 
            echo '<div class="pnoright"></div>';
         echo '</div> </div>';   
      echo '<div class="cover"> '.$covers[3]['introtext'].' </div>';
?>
```

Comment: Well i guess you can't do it with php or it's too complicated to do, I'd suggest to count content height with javascript.

Comment: how i count height of <p> <h1> <h2> <h3> <img> in any no of occurrences with php... im asking for php as i need this height to calculated to adjust the portion i extract from the whole lot... ? or is there any other way... ?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to simplify code, so many mysql queries for nothing...

My offer (works the same way):

```
<?php
$qry="SELECT `introtext` FROM `sdad_content` WHERE `catid`= '2' AND `state`='1' ORDER BY `id`";
$get_db->setQuery($qry);
$results = $get_db->loadObjectList();
if (count($results)){
    foreach($results as $key => $item){
        if($key%2==0){
            $class='even';
            $pnoclass="pnoright";
        } else {
            $class='odd';
            $pnoclass="pnoleft";
        }
        echo '<div class="text '.$class.' "> <div class="page"> '.$cover; 
        echo '<div class="'.$pnoclass.' ">  </div>';
        echo '</div> </div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Less code, only 1 query (insted of N) and same result :)

Comment: don't forget to recommend using Joomla 2.5 coding standards for the database query ;)

Comment: oh cool... that's much refined and clean code...  but i need help/suggestions for "suppose i have all the content of a book in a joomla article and i want to dynamically load a portion of it as a page to make the book page and so on make pages till end of article... this seems doable if i only have text with fix no of lines. But the problem is the content can have images and headings as well... so how can i dynamically vary the portion of the article to be extracted for a single page length based on contents to avoid overflow of book page"... page height is supposed say 700px...

Comment: slight modified this code as here (http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=629429) i found that loadAssocList is FASTER then loadObjectList ... so using <pre> $rows = $get_db->loadAssocList();
                          $total_pages= count($rows);
                          //echo count($results);
                          if($total_pages) {
                          for($i=0; $i<$total_pages; $i++){ </pre>

Comment: well if you could send me a link to your dev page, i could suggest some kind of javascript / css solution for page height.

Comment: its on localhost but same as this one...  this http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs...

Comment: Can't you just set css style #book-wrapper .page {overflow: hidden;} ?